# How to add multithreading with SuperSimpleTcp C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, websocket, tcp

my code is similar to the supersimpletcp documentation on github

```
using SuperSimpleTcp;

void Main(string[] args)
{
  // instantiate
  SimpleTcpServer server = new SimpleTcpServer("127.0.0.1:9000");

  // set events
  server.Events.ClientConnected += ClientConnected;
  server.Events.ClientDisconnected += ClientDisconnected;
  server.Events.DataReceived += DataReceived;

  // let's go!
  server.Start();

  // once a client has connected...
  server.Send("[ClientIp:Port]", "Hello, world!");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ClientConnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"[{e.IpPort}] client connected");
}

static void ClientDisconnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"[{e.IpPort}] client disconnected: {e.Reason}");
}

static void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"[{e.IpPort}]: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data.Array, 0, e.Data.Count)}");
}
```

However, the coding can only run in one direction, server - client

Can supersimpletcp coding be able to run multi-directionally using C# threading like:

- client01 - server
- client02 - server
- client03 - server

Comment: It is not clear what the actual question is, or why multi threading is relevant in this context. "The coding can only run in one direction" and "multi directionally" does not make sense to me. Are you asking if/how multiple clients can connect to the same server? How to do bi-directional communication? Or if clients can talk to each other?